# Python Selenium select xpath with variable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate a visible element that will change based on what the user enters on the website. I am successful if use the follow with a static xpath search string:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Default-Test']")))
```

Default-Test will change arbitrarily and i have how to get this value but I have not been successful using a variable in the xpath search:

Test method 1 Does not work

```
dtg_found = "Default-Test"
```

Test method 2 does not work, this is the actual method for locating the value

```
dtg_found = driver.find_element_by_name("result[0].col[1].stringVal").get_attribute("value")

dtg_opt_1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "\"//a[text()='" + dtg_found + "']" + '"')))
```

Comment: How many quotation marks do you have in there?

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing up the escapes "\" and tried concatenating the string together without "\". Finally got it work with the following:         dtg_opt_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text()," + " '" + dtg_found + "'" + ")]")

Comment: If you've resolved the question, then you should either delete it, or provide an answer below (and accept it) so that the question won't clutter up the unanswered questions page.

Comment: What gave you the impression that you should have a `\"` at the beginning of the XPath expression?

Comment: @LarsH I am a bit new to python but I was trying to concatenate the xpath search string with variable. Because the search string as mixed quotes I thought I could use \ to escape the following quote. I was clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution to the issue I was encountering.  Tried reworking the string and the related escapes '\' but was not successful. Did however get the following working. I am not clear why this worked.

```
dtg_opt_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text()," + " '" + dtg_found + "'" + ")]")
```